# Can't download Minecraft for Windows 10 on new computer

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently got a new computer, and wanted to play with friends through Minecraft for Windows 10, but I can't figure out how to download it. Whenever I go to the game "Minecraft for Windows 10" it says I don't own it; when I go to the game titled as "Minecraft", it says I own it. 

But when I click on 'Install on my devices', I get a pop-up saying

> It looks like you don't have any applicable device(s) linked to your
>   Microsoft account. to install, sign in on a device with your Microsoft
>   account.

I am signed into my account and i don't know what else to do since the only other button on screen is "buy as gift".

[image]

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I got the game with a code from when they were giving out codes if you bought Minecraft Java edition.

Comment: Looks to me like the Xbox version.

Comment: @dly [Xbox Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live) has replaced Games for Windows Live, and is available on Windows 10 systems as well.

Comment: @BOXXY-what Do you use the same account for XBox Live and Windows 10? I never linked my Windows installation to an email address, and had similar issues, in XBox Live (with screen captures), and in the Microsoft Store, installing apps.

Comment: @Joachim yes my accounts are linked but i dont use xbox live i use the xbox app on pc (not sure if its different or not)

Comment: @Joachim sure, but there are still two different versions for Minecraft on Xbox and Win 10. Afaik the Xbox version cannot be installed on PC, only streamed.

Comment: @dly But I think the version he talks about is [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/minecraft/9nblggh537bl?activetab=pivot%3Aregionofsystemrequirementstab), which mentions Windows 10 under system requirements.

Comment: You're signed into your account in the store, but did you add your Microsoft account to your PC's account as well? (Windows settings > accounts)

Answer (score -1):

Mojang is migrating all java player account to microsoft account. If you are having trouble downloading, its because you havent migrated. Now ive migrated my account a while back, uninstalled minecraft, and then tried to install a few months later but it didnt like it. The solution was going through the migration process again (this is done on the mojang site). If you click on your account in the mojang site you should see it gives you the steps to do so. Once i migrated the account again, I was able to download the java edition (which automatically went to the windows 10/11 edition). Now, go into search bar and click the minecraft launcher, should do its updates and such, and then it will take you to your login. Now, the first login (your original login info) will not be valid anymore. This means the account migration as a success. All you have to do is click the small 'X' button beside the login. Then click 'go back' and you should see two options for sign in. Click sign with microsoft instead of mojang and login using your microsoft account info. Hope this helps.